# How do I show data from Mysql Database by line by line using a separator?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm inserting my form data to Mysql Databasee in **One Column** called `notesUpdate`. Following is my php script which is inserting/Updating data to database but I use separator `___` because in this columns I'm inserting many data. I want to show this all single data line by line which is end with `___` . So that I'm using second Php script.

**Insert/Update php script**

```
$contetn =  $_POST['contentText'];
$cdid = $_POST['cdid'];
$contetn .= "___"; 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE contact_details SET notesUpdate = CONCAT(notesUpdate, '$contetn') WHERE cdid = '$cdid' LIMIT 1");
```

**Show Php Script**

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT notesUpdate FROM contact_details WHERE cdid = '$id'");
$row =  mysql_fetch_array($query);
$notes = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($row['notesUpdate'])));
$ex =  explode("___", $notes);
$ex[0];
$ex[1];
```

**Show data should be look like this:**

```
Hello one data
Hello two data
Hello three data
```

But I've no idea how can I get this ? Can you suggest me or show my how can I get this ? Thanks.

**Update:**

This is the form where all data is showing :

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><h2>All Notes</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cdid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="cdid"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea cols="65" rows="5" name="notesContent" style="padding:0; margin:0;"> <?php echo $ex[0]; ?> </textarea>  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Notes" id="editNotes" class="submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code is extremely vulnerable to injection...

Comment: And whats your error message? Plus consider in updating your code to change MYSQL_* functions as it is deprecated. You should use MYSQLi_* functions or PDO

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks for your great suggestion. I'm I'll use this MYSQLi_

Comment: @JorgeCampos I've no error message. My questions is how do show the data in line by line using the separator ?

Comment: That will be good for you. And for your question, you want to show all the values of your array `$ex` inside the `textarea` tag, is that it ?

Comment: Yes that's right but should be show line by line using the separator. So that it's not look like one paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion on the comments what you whant is just a `for` or a `foreach` on your `ex` array inside that `textarea` tag. But there is a catch. If you just iterate through your array it will show just one line after other because you didn't add the `enter` char so it will be like:

```
<textarea cols="65" rows="5" name="notesContent" style="padding:0; margin:0;"><?php foreach( $ex as $value ) { echo $value . "\r\n"; } ?></textarea>
```

Note: It has to be an inline code because the HTML tag `textarea` will add every character you put inside it.

If you want a prettier code use like this:

```
<?php
    $text = "";
    foreach( $ex as $value ){
        $text .= $value . "\r\n";
    }
?>
<textarea cols="65" rows="5" name="notesContent" style="padding:0; margin:0;"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
```

Or even simplier

```
<textarea cols="65" rows="5" name="notesContent" style="padding:0; margin:0;"><?php echo str_replace( "___", "\r\n", $notes ); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Oh. It's working fine. But I don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: What did you don't understand ?